# Custom Textbox Even not running

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

I wrote a custom textbox for a program that is designed to give me database values without a lot of converts or checks and to have custom text input. It had a few different modes, such as an auto formatting date box and SSN. It worked great in VB.NET, but now that I'm learning C# and I'm remaking the program in C# for practice, I'm hitting a snag with the conversion. None of the events will fire.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class DBTextBox : TextBox {
    private void InitializeComponent() {
            SuspendLayout();
            Enter += new EventHandler(DBTextBox_Enter);
            KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(On_Key_Press);
            KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(On_Key_Up);
            Leave += new EventHandler(Control_Leave);
            ResumeLayout(false);
    }

    public enum StyleTypes {
        DateBox,
        SSNBox,
        PhoneBox,
        TextBox,
        IntegerBox,
        DecimalBox
    }

    private StyleTypes Type { get; set; }
    public StyleTypes StyleType {
        get { return Type; }
        set { Type = value; }
    }

    private string _Default_Value { get; set; }
    public string Default_Value {
        get { return _Default_Value; }
        set { _Default_Value = value; }
    }

    private bool _AutoUpperCase = false;
    public bool AutoUpperCase {
        get { return _AutoUpperCase; }
        set { _AutoUpperCase = value; }
    }

    private bool _AutoUpperCaseFirstCharOnly = false;
    public bool AutoUpperCaseFirstCharOnly {
        get { return _AutoUpperCaseFirstCharOnly; }
        set { _AutoUpperCaseFirstCharOnly = value; }
    }

    private void On_Key_Up(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Back) {
            if (Type == StyleTypes.DateBox) {
                if (TextLength == 2 && Text.Contains("//") == false) {
                    Text = Text + "/";
                    SelectionStart = Text.Length + 1;
                }
                if (TextLength == 4 && Text.Substring(1, 1) == "//" && Text.Substring(3, 1) != "//" && CharCount('/') <= 1) {
                    Text = Text + "/";
                    SelectionStart = Text.Length + 1;
                }
                if (TextLength == 5 && Text.Substring(2, 1) == "//" && CharCount('/') <= 1) {
                    Text = Text + "/";
                    SelectionStart = Text.Length + 1;
                }
                if (Text.Contains("//")) {
                    Text = Text.Replace(@"//", @"/");
                    SelectionStart = Text.Length + 1;
                }
            }
            if (Type == StyleTypes.SSNBox) {
                MaxLength = 11;
                if (TextLength == 3 || TextLength == 6) {
                    Text = Text + "-";
                    SelectionStart = Text.Length + 1;
                }
            }
            if (Type == StyleTypes.PhoneBox) {
                MaxLength = 14;
                if (TextLength == 3 && Text.Contains('(') == false) {
                    Text = "(" + Text + ") ";
                    SelectionStart = Text.Length + 1;
                }
                if (TextLength == 9) {
                    Text = Text + "-";
                    SelectionStart = Text.Length + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Control_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (Type == StyleTypes.DateBox) {
            if (DateTime.TryParse(Text, out DateTime i)) {
                BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Window);
                Text = Convert.ToDateTime(Text).ToShortDateString();
            } else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Text)) {
                BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Window);
                Text = string.Empty;
            } else {
                BackColor = Color.Salmon;
            }
        }
    }

    private void On_Key_Press(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
        if (Type == StyleTypes.DateBox) {
            if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) == false && char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) == false) {
                if (e.KeyChar == '/' && CharCount('/') <= 1) { } else { e.Handled = true; }
            }
        }
        if (Type == StyleTypes.PhoneBox) {
            if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) == false && char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) == false && e.KeyChar != '-' && e.KeyChar != '(' && e.KeyChar != ' ') {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
        if (Type == StyleTypes.SSNBox) {
            if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) == false && char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) == false && e.KeyChar != '-') {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
        if (Type == StyleTypes.DecimalBox) {
            if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) == false && char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) == false) {
                if ((e.KeyChar == '.' && CharCount('.') < 1) || (e.KeyChar == '-' && CharCount('-') < 1)) { } else { e.Handled = true; }
            }
        }
        if (Type == StyleTypes.IntegerBox) {
            if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) == false && char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) == false) {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private int CharCount(char Character) {
        char[] Chars = Text.ToCharArray();
        int Count = 0;
        foreach (var Item in Chars) {
            if (Item == Character) {
                Count += 1;
            }
        }
        return Count;
    }

    [Description("The Text in the box, returns null if Empty or White spaces")]
    public string DBText {
        get { if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Text)) { return null; } else { return Text; } }
        set { if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) { Text = null; } else { Text = value; } }
    }

    [Description("The returned Date if the Text is a date.")]
    public DateTime? DBDate {
        get { if (DateTime.TryParse(Text, out DateTime i)) { return Convert.ToDateTime(Text); } else { return null; } }
        set { Convert.ToDateTime(value).ToShortDateString(); }
    }

    public decimal? DBDecimal {
        get { if (decimal.TryParse(Text, out decimal i)) { return Convert.ToDecimal(Text); } else { return null; } }
        set { Text = value.ToString(); }
    }

    public int? DBInt {
        get { if (int.TryParse(Text, out int i) && Convert.ToInt32(Text) > int.MinValue && Convert.ToInt32(Text) < int.MaxValue) { return Convert.ToInt32(Text); } else { return null; } }
        set { Text = value.ToString(); }
    }

    public short? DBShort {
        get { if (short.TryParse(Text, out short i)) { return Convert.ToInt16(Text); } else { return null; } }
        set { Text = value.ToString(); }
    }

    private string UppercaseFirstLetter(string Input) {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Input)) { return Input; }
        char[] array = Input.ToCharArray();
        array[0] = char.ToUpper(array[0]);
        bool UpperCaseNextLetter = true;
        int LastCharPos = array.Count() - 1;
        if (_AutoUpperCaseFirstCharOnly) { LastCharPos = 1; }
        for (int i = 0; i <= LastCharPos; i++) {
            if (UpperCaseNextLetter == true) {
                array[i] = char.ToUpper(array[i]);
                UpperCaseNextLetter = false;
            } else {
                array[i] = char.ToLower(array[i]);
            }
            if (array[i] == ' ') {
                UpperCaseNextLetter = true;
            }
        }
        return new string(array);
    }

    private void DBTextBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (Type == StyleTypes.DateBox) {
            if (DateTime.TryParse(Text, out DateTime i)) {
                SelectionStart = 0;
                SelectionLength = Text.Length;
            }
        }
        if (Type == StyleTypes.TextBox && Text.Length > 0 && _Default_Value.Length > 0) {
            if (Text == _Default_Value) {
                SelectionStart = 0;
                SelectionLength = Text.Length;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What do I need to do to get the events to fire?

Edit: Here it is on the Debug Form I created to test it;

```
partial class frmDebug {
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        if (disposing && (components != null)) {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent() {
            this.txtDate = new DBTextBox();
            this.cmdSet = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // txtDate
            // 
            this.txtDate.AutoUpperCase = false;
            this.txtDate.AutoUpperCaseFirstCharOnly = false;
            this.txtDate.DBDate = null;
            this.txtDate.DBDecimal = null;
            this.txtDate.DBInt = null;
            this.txtDate.DBShort = null;
            this.txtDate.DBText = null;
            this.txtDate.Default_Value = null;
            this.txtDate.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(72, 52);
            this.txtDate.Name = "txtDate";
            this.txtDate.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.txtDate.StyleType = DBTextBox.StyleTypes.DateBox;
            this.txtDate.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // cmdSet
            // 
            this.cmdSet.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(68, 128);
            this.cmdSet.Name = "cmdSet";
            this.cmdSet.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.cmdSet.TabIndex = 1;
            this.cmdSet.Text = "Set";
            this.cmdSet.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.cmdSet.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.cmdSet_Click);
            // 
            // frmDebug
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 261);
            this.Controls.Add(this.cmdSet);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txtDate);
            this.Name = "frmDebug";
            this.Text = "frmDebug";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button cmdSet;
    public DBTextBox txtDate;
}
```

I don't have any code on the Form so this is what it looks like;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class frmDebug : Form {
    public frmDebug() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Will you please show us the code where the text box is declared/initialized?

Comment: You don't call InitializeComponent from inside the TextBox.  But a class doesn't have to listen to their own events.  Use the overrides instead, example: `protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e) {...}`

Comment: Please make this an answer so I can upvote and mark as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LarsTech has a **better** and **more correct** solution:

> You don't call InitializeComponent from inside the TextBox. But a
>   class doesn't have to listen to their own events. Use the overrides
>   instead, example: protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
>   {...}

**My original answer:**

It looks like you'll probably just need to add a constructor for the `DBTextBox` class that will call your private `InitializeComponent()` method. It should look something like this:

```
public DBTextBox()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: I'm upvoting this because it worked. However LarsTech's solution feels more correct. Plus the auto-complete kicks in when I do an override which makes me feel safe.

Comment: @Kayot Definitely, I agree that is a better and more correct solution.

Comment: Just add it to your answer.